# SQL Server convert INT to DATE - "MS DTC has cancelled distribution transaction"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a db that is storing date keys as `int` in the format `YYYYMMDD`. I need to convert these to a date.

I've found that I can do this with a single record using a query in this form:

```
SELECT
        recordID
        , CAST(CAST(dateID AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) AS recordDate
FROM
        records
WHERE
        recordID IN (1)
```

But if I try to do this to multiple records (e.g. `recordID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5`)

I get the following message:

`The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.`

I have checked each record individually, though, and the query runs fine if only being run for one record.

Also somewhat odd is if I try this same query on another one our databases (also SQL Server) it runs fine.

Comment: When searching for the error message, this was the first result: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/11/06/sql-server-msg-1206-level-18-state-118-the-microsoft-distributed-transaction-coordinator-ms-dtc-has-cancelled-the-distributed-transaction/ Does any of this apply or resolve the issue?

Comment: Or this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1170215-146-1.aspx

Comment: You may have a bad trigger that works on a single record but fails with multiple records.  As @Shawn mentioned, this might involve a linked server as well.